# Tkinter image not displaying inside class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

**This thread has been closed:**

EDIT: The solution to the problem was the fact that when I called the module, I had no mainloop resulting in the image only showing at the very start.

I am currently creating a tkinter application, and was neating everything up by giving my different pages their own classes and modules.
What has been happening was when I was debugging the code, all the images were working fine until I fixed this one error.

I was just this line:

```
Button (window, text="SUBMIT", width=8, command=Loginpage.change_home()).place(x = 220, y = 365)
```

It was just a simple issue, I had just forgotten to change the name of my function. But when I fixed it, none of the images are being displayed. Their are no error messages or anything, and everything else works fine but the images aren't showing.

```
    def __init__(self, window):
        page = Frame(window)
        window.geometry("500x430")

        self.logo = PhotoImage(file="images\TheImage.pgm")
        
        global loginresult
        

        loginresult = Text(window, width=35, height=1, wrap=WORD, bg="black", fg="red", borderwidth=0)

    def change(change_to):
        return(change_to)
    
    def change_home():
        change_to = "home"
        Loginpage.change(change_to)
        
    def change_create():
        change_to = "create"
        Loginpage.change(change_to)
        
    def login(self, window):
        
        window.configure(background="black")
        
        image = Label(window, image=self.logo, bg="black").pack(side="top")
    
        Label (window, text="Username", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").place(x=220,y=260)
        Label (window, text="Password", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").place(x=220,y=310)


        textentryusername = Entry(window, width=50, bg="white")
        textentrypassword = Entry(window, width=50, bg="white")
        textentryusername.place(x=107,y=285)
        textentrypassword.place(x=107,y=335)

        username = textentryusername.get()
        password = textentrypassword.get()


        Button (window, text="SUBMIT", width=8, command=Loginpage.change_home()).place(x = 220, y = 365)
        print(username + " " + password)
        
        Button (window, text="Don't have an account?", width=18, command=Loginpage.change_create()).place(x = 185, y = 400)
        
        loginresult.place(x=107,y=230)
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to add that I am running this as a module, so that is why I am not calling the functions on this page.

Also, I have put together a minimal reproducible example:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = Tk()

class Loginpage:
    def __init__(self, window):
        page = Frame(window)
        window.geometry("500x430")
        self.logo = PhotoImage(file="Test.pgm")
        
    def login(self, window):
        image = Label(window, image=self.logo, bg="black").pack(side="top")

Loginpage(window).login(window)
```

In the example above, I am still getting the problem, without an error message or anything.

Comment: At a glance it looks like you forgot to call the login() method. Did you mean to add `self.login()` to the bottom of `__init__`? You'll need to show a [mcve] for specific help.